# New Uploads in Firebase App Distribution Cannot be Downloaded Suddenly

Tags: google-play, firebase-app-distribution, internal-app-sharing

Our team has been using Firebase Distribution to test our apps without encountering any issues. However, today, we are unable to download anymore. The Playstore page shows something like this:[image]

What we did so far:

- Cleared Play Store data and cache.
- Cleared App Tester data and cache.
- Restarted the device.
- Followed Firebase Distribution FAQs.
- Followed the Play Store troubleshooting guide.
- Tried different builds.
- Installed on multiple devices.

We also noticed that for those older working builds, the Play Store page shows the Internal test version. However, for the newly uploaded build, it displays the actual Play Store page of our app.

Anyone else encountering this issue?

Comment: This seems to be a general issue, also affecting our team with multiple apps.

Comment: Hi all, Anthony from the Firebase App Distribution team here. Thanks for the report. We're aware of this issue and are investigating it this morning. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: This issue is resolved for us starting this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @shervinox the problem was solved, and new uploads are working again. However, keep in mind that the previous ones still failing.